# apache2: render web pages

Tags: apache, apache2

I am having following configuration in my apache2.conf:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/temp/pages"

<Directory "/var/www/temp/pages/">
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/temp/scripts/">
  AllowOverride None
  Options ExecCGI
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The intention is that in one directory I store my web pages and in another - the scripts. I have a sample index.html file placed in /var/www/temp/pages/ dir but when I try to access from browser:

```
<ip>/cgi-bin/index.html
```

I get below error:

```
Exec format error ....
Prematrure end of script
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You are trying to access an html page as a script. Shouldn't it be `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/temp/scripts"`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I just changed ScriptAlis to Alias and it worked perfectly